# Change the relative order with which gvim search for executable files

Tags: vim

Gvim will search the executable files in $PATH, $VIMRUNTIME(the folder where gvim.exe locate) and the current folder. The folder of $PATH have the highest priority.
Suppose i place a cygwin version “find.exe" in the folder where gvim.exe locate.
and i want gvim to call this cygwin version of "find.exe" instead of the windows version of "find.exe" for ":!find", how could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `$PATH` in your `~/.vimrc`; this will avoid messing with any other Windows program (well, except for those that are launched from inside Vim - do check their compatibility).

```
:let $PATH = 'C:\cygwin\bin;' . $PATH
```

---

If other Cygwin binaries still interfere, copy Cygwin's `find.exe` to another folder (be it `$VIMRUNTIME` or a fresh directory somewhere else), and prepend that to $PATH.

```
:let $PATH = $VIMRUNTIME . ';' . $PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put `C:\cygwin\bin` (or your equivalent) at the start of your `$PATH` it will find the cygwin binary first and use that one rather than the windows binary.

Comment: Exactely, the way you suggest could do. But i don't want to put C:\cygwin\bin at the start of my $PATH in windows because this will override some windows binaries like "find" and other programs on my laptop may not work due to that. What could i do except the way you suggest?

Comment: I agree you with that, but gvim do call the binaries if you put them in the $VIMRUNTIME. Like if i put cscope.exe in it, it will call "cscope.exe" when i type "!cscope" in gvim.

Comment: No, `ln` doesn't work even though i did it in cygwin. gvim will still call the windows version "find.exe" first.

Comment: I don't think this will affect any other windows programs, my `$PATH` is set like that and doesn't make a difference to anything I've used.

Comment: tom, thanks for you assistance, i think i will just try your suggestion